# Android MediaSession buttons

Tags: android, android-mediasession

> Allows interaction with media controllers, volume keys, media buttons, and transport controls.

The MediaSession documentation states that it works with media buttons and transport controls. Does that only include physical buttons on a device, or can you implement UI Buttons that trigger MediaSession callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

It sure does.

First you need a service that listens to media button events, so declare it from you manifest like so

```
     <service android:name="com.example.android.MediaPlaybackService" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
   </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

In that service you should initialize a `MediaSessionCompat` object and pass the intent you receive along with it to the `MediaButtonReceiver` like so

```
    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSessionCompat = ...;

 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mMediaSessionCompat, intent);
   return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }
```

You also might want to create an instance of `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` and set it with

```
setCallback()
```

This is where you will actually control the media that is playing
You can also invoke these transport controls through your own UI using an instance of `MediaControllerCompat` using it's `getTransportControls()` method

More here
[MediaButtonReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html)